# Computer bluescreens when compiling Visual C++ 2010 project

Tags: windows-7, bsod, visual-studio-2010, compile

Occasionally, roughly once every few hours (although it can be less or more frequent), my computer will bluescreen or sometimes just shut down with only a black screen when I compile my visual C++ project. It does not always happen when I compile the project, and has happened with other projects in the past.

I am using windows 7. When it actually forms a blue screen rather than just shutting down with a black screen, it is too quick to read before the computer shuts down. Are there any likely causes and is there anything I should do prior to the next blue screen to find the cause of the issue?

Comment: Do the BSOD happen outside VC++ ? Anyway you can try to check the System Events or the minidumps for answers about the BSOD's.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I haven't noticed any BSODs outside of VC++ recently, but there might have been some possibly unrelated ones a while ago.

Comment: upload the dmp files, so that we can look at them with Windbg.